# get Filtered result in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to have filtered result based on 'some string value' from output of a command.
For example, i need to get MAC address from output of ipconfig.
i tried

```
 ipconfig /all | Select-String -Pattern "Physical Address"
```

I am getting all MAC Addresss like

```
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA
 Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA
```

I want to have only Mac address of wifi adapter.
SO output would be AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA. 
I dont want entire line

```
Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : AA-AA-AA-AA-AA-AA
```

Comment: What is the header of the section where your wifi physical address is? Are there any other physical addresses in that section other than your wifi ones?

Comment: It says, 'Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:'
Yes. There are total 5 physical address in ipconfig /all output.

Comment: To clarify, in the Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection section, there are 5?

Comment: Nop. there is only one mac addrs  under wireless adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on my system:

```
$Wireless_Adapter_Regex  =
@'
(?ms).+?Wireless LAN adapter .+?
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : (\S+)
'@

(ipconfig /all | out-string) -match $Wireless_Adapter_Regex > $null
$matches[1]

C4-D9-87-41-37-F1
```

Comment: This does solves the problem. Brilliant way to get regex match string.
Thanks alot.

Comment: $matches[1] -replace "-",":" 
if you need a mac address with digits separated by colons

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command:

```
ipconfig /all | Select-String -Pattern "\w\w-\w\w-\w\w-\w\w-\w\w-\w\w" -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

Comment: This does not at all address OP's question - how can he restrict the matches to only those of wifi adapter interfaces?

Comment: @Krzysztof I really appreciate your quick reply.
is there a way to filter this to get ONLY MAC address of wireless adapter?

Answer (score 0):

`ipconfig /all | Select-String -Pattern "Physical Address"`  can be further extended to split output by ':' delimiter and display 2nd field. Example is given below.

```
PS C:\Users\jump> ipconfig /all | Select-String -SimpleMatch Physical
 -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.ToString().split(":")[1]}
 B8-AC-6F-28-08-C5
```